# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty \sin (x^a) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I can rewrite this integral as $\int_0^1 \sin (x^a) dx$ + $\int_1^\infty \sin (x^a) dx$.

Since $|\sin (x^a)|\le 1$, the first integral is convergent because of majorant criterion.

For the second one, I read somewhere on the internet that for $a\lt0$, $\sin (x^a)$ behaves as
$x^a$ when $x$ approaches infinity which implies that integral is convergent for $a\lt-1$.

I suppose this is due to limit criterion for integrals but how can the limit criterion be used if the integrand isn't a non-negative function?

Comment: Try integration by part.

Comment: Is it $(\sin x)^a$ or $\sin(x^a)$?

Comment: It is sin (x^a)

Comment: Make the change of variables $t=x^a$ and then use the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals) for improper integrals.

Comment: I already solved it that way but I'd like to know does what I wrote above make sense

Comment: @JurgenKlop You should have said this in your question. You can use $\left| {\sin (x^a )} \right| < x^a$ which is valid for all $x>0$ and $a\in \mathbb R$. See [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/proof-that-sin-x-x-for-all-positive-real-numbers).

Comment: I don't get it. I mean I know your inequality holds true , but I don't get how that affects what I have written above

Comment: OK, then note that $\sin(x^a)$ *is* non-negative if $x\geq 1$ and $a\leq 0$.